# Dataset tiene 1393 filas, pero solo se muestran 24 de ellas (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net

Estimados amigos,
Estoy llenando un Dataset utilizando un DataGridView en Visual Basic 2013 para luego enviarlo a Crystal Report. He podido comprobar que la tabla "Cliente" de mi Dataset contiene 1393 registros, pero solo se muestran 24. Paradógicamente, en las siguientes "ejecuciones" de la aplicación se generan 26 registros, y ahora que sigo ejecutando (sin hacer modificaciones a mi código) se muestra solo 1 registro. Adjunto imagen donde en el PUNTO 1 es un bucle que me permite comprobar registro a registro el contenido de mi tabla y sí corresponde con el contenido del DataGridView. En el PUNTO 2 creo que está el error, ya que no estoy muy seguro si estoy haciendo las cosas bien. No tengo error en tiempo de ejecución del IDE. Espero sus comentarios y quedo muy agradecido. Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ricky: No se entiende bien cual es tu punto, o que es lo que deseas hacer. Creo que tienes algunos errores de concepto. Si quieres imprimir en el reporte el contenido del dgListaUnica deberías colocar como DataSource del reporte el DataSource del DataGrid. Entonces eso abré otra pregunta: ¿Cómo cargas el DataGrid dgListaUnica? Y teniendo en cuenta que todo esto lo hacés en el Load del Formulario me genera muchisima controversia tu código.

Comment: Agustín, definitivamente como bien dices son errores de concepto (yo estoy aprendiendo a medida que estoy haciendo este proyecto) mi campo de desarrollo es web. De todas maneras voy a probar lo que mencionas y ahora que leo esta respuesta tuya, recuerdo que si pues, puedo usar el DataSource del DataGridView directamente sin la necesidad de usar Datasets y eso es justamente lo que estoy haciendo. Ya carga mi reporte en Crystal Reports. Gracias por tu soporte, en serio, me ayudas mucho.

Comment: No hay porque en todo esto se aprende haciendo! Este sitio es una ayuda enorme ya que nos permite interactuar con colegas que estan en líos y darles una mano o al menos indicarles algún camino al que puedan apuntar.

Comment: Así es, en lo personal me daba igual hacerlo en VB o C#, la verdad tengo más experiencia en lenguajes como Java y quizás me hubiera resultado más fácil e intuitivo hacerlo en C#, pero ya está, casi ya he terminado jeje, un abrazo hermano, ¡buena salud!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno solucioné mi problema haciendo lo que dice el siguiente video, aunque esta vez no utilicé datasets, sino solamente datatables.. al final el propósito era llenar un reporte con la información de un DataGridView:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=bezhqdUwqV8